# Problem with sudo apt-get update 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

```
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-apps-dependencies-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-apps-dependencies-xenial.list:3
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu oneiric Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/folke-schwinning/personal/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/folke-schwinning/personal/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies    /ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-apps-dependencies-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-apps-dependencies-xenial.list:3
```

I tried solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) link
But not getting solution

I tried to install *GRASS GIS, OSGeo, etc*

Answer (score 0):

1. Go inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and look for `moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list` and delete it if more than one entry is present.
2. Perform the following step for `noobslab-ubuntu-apps-dependencies-xenial.list` as well.
3. Where the lines are starting with **E**, it means error. please check whether the URL is correct or not.
4. For all the lines with **W**, those are warning. According to the logs we can conclude that the URL which you have put are not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

## First

For the `configured multiple times` error, in `terminal`, do this:

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list*
```

You'll probably see this:

```
moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list
moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2
moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:3
moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:4
```

Leave `moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list` alone, and delete the remaining 3 with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/source.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:2
sudo rm /etc/apt/source.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:3
sudo rm /etc/apt/source.list.d/moka-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list:4
```

## Second

For the `404 Not Found` errors, see my previous answer to this same question at [how to reset update sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851277/how-to-reset-update-sources/851341#851341)

## Third

Ignore the SHA1 errors.

## Fourth

For the `repository can't be authenticated` errors, install `y-ppa-manager` and update the gpg authorization keys. In `terminal`, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then start `PPA Manager` from the Unity dashboard.